# Creating Azure Functions Targeting .NET 7

Tags: azure-functions, .net-7.0

I don’t see .NET 7 Isolated as an option when I try to create a new Azure Functions app in Visual Studio 17.4 (Windows version).

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried this? Delete %LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools folder and relauch your Visual Studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use the Isolated model, you shall set your environment variable `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` to `dotnet-isolated` and use these NuGet packages:

- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk`

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) and especially [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker), where you can find lot of samples (with .NET7 too!)

Comment: Is it even possible to create the template with visual studio? This answer is not helping me so far as I get "There is no Functions runtime available that matches the version specified in the project"

Comment: @NorbertHuurnink I can't see the option for dotnet7 in template creation, but you can choose the `dotnet6 (Isolated)` one and then manually upgrade the csproj to `net7.0`

Comment: @Krusty when I do that (manually upgrade to net7.0) I get a build error "Invalid combination of TargetFramework and AzureFunctionsVersion is set"

Comment: @Alain Does your csproj file target both v4 function version and net7? `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>`

Comment: Any updates on this? I also cannot see any options to create a .NET 7 Azure Function in Visual Studio 17.5.4 and I have the latest Azure Functions Core tools and .NET 7 SDK installed.

Comment: @OliverNilsen I can see the option now `.NET 7.0 Isolated` under `Functions worker` menu